# Spring MVC & Jackson JSON serialization

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, serialization, jackson

I have question regarding entities serialization to JSON using Spring MVC & Jackson.
I have following entities:

```
@Table(name = «A»)
class A {

 @Column(name = «Id»)
 Integer id;

 @Column(name = «Name»)
 String name;

 @JoinColumn(name = «B_Id»)
 B b;
}

@Table(name = «B»)
class B {
 @Column(name = «Id»)
 Integer id;

 @Column(name = «Name»)
 String name;
}
```

and I have following REST controller which returns JSON response (using Jackson integration & Spring Data repository):

```
@RestController
public class AController {

 @Inject
 ARepository aRepository;

 @RequestMapping(value = «index»)
 List<A> getIndex() {
    return aRepository.findAll();
 }
}
```

I want to exclude from the response "name" fields (from A & B classes). So the desired JSON response should be like:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  b: {
    id: 1
  }
}]
```

I know that I can use @JsonView from Jackson library, but in this case (as far as I know) I need to put additional @JsonView annotations to the entity fields.

I want to keep my domain entities clean from UI related stuff and configure response JSON field list at the UI layer.

For example:

```
 @JSON_ENTITY(fieldList = [‘id’, ‘b.id’]) //specify field list explicitly
 //or
 @JSON_ENTITY(view = MyJsonView.class) // that's also would be good

 @RequestMapping(value = «index»)
 List<A> getIndex() {
    return aRepository.findAll();
 }
```

Do you have any clues on how it can be done with Spring?

Comment: You appear to be using Spring Data so maybe: https://spring.io/blog/2014/05/21/what-s-new-in-spring-data-dijkstra#projections-in-spring-data-rest

Comment: did you try to use `@JsonIgnore` for name property ?